# Minimax algorithm only returning specific set of values

Tags: python, algorithm, minimax

I implemented a minimax algorithm for a basic tic-tac-toe AI in Python like this:

```
def minimax(currentBoard, player):
    if isGameOver(currentBoard):
        score = evaluate(currentBoard)
        return score
    for cell in getEmptySpots(currentBoard):
        x = cell[0]
        y = cell[1]
        currentBoard[x][y] = player
        bestScore = -1000000
        score = minPlay(currentBoard, -player)
        currentBoard[x][y] = 0
        if score > bestScore:
            bestScore = score
            bestMove = cell
            print('Best move:')
            print(bestMove)
            print('\n')
        return bestMove

def minPlay(currentBoard, player):
    if isGameOver(currentBoard):
        score = evaluate(currentBoard)
        return score
    for cell in getEmptySpots(currentBoard):
        x = cell[0]
        y = cell[1]
        currentBoard[x][y] = player
        bestScore = 1000000
        score = maxPlay(currentBoard, -player)
        currentBoard[x][y] = 0
        if score < bestScore:
            bestScore = score
        return bestScore

def maxPlay(currentBoard, player):
    if isGameOver(currentBoard):
        score = evaluate(currentBoard)
        return score
    for cell in getEmptySpots(currentBoard):
        x = cell[0]
        y = cell[1]
        currentBoard[x][y] = player
        bestScore = -1000000
        score = minPlay(currentBoard, -player)
        currentBoard[x][y] = 0
        if score > bestScore:
            bestScore = score
        return bestScore
```

The other supporting functions are pretty self-explanatory. However, this script does not function as it should. For example, it always seems to begin by picking [0,0] and then proceeding with a relatively constant set of moves, even when better moves are available. Also, given the following state (and states in general where a winning move is available):

[image]

where `1` represents the human and `-1` represents the computer, the computer picks the move `[2][1]` as the best move, instead of `[2][2]` or `[1][2]` which would both result in a win.

I have gone through a number of questions relating to minimax implementation in different languages and as far as I can tell my code logically makes sense. Thus I'm unsure as to what the problem could be.
My full code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/YVCChy3m).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues.  The first is the logic problem in @Flopp 's answer.  The second is that `isGameOver` does not return true when there are no more moves left.  Scores of `0` get returned as the initial max or min score.

here:

```
def minPlay(currentBoard, player):
    if isGameOver(currentBoard):
        score = evaluate(currentBoard)
        return score
```

The relevant (fixed) line is here (it's not beautiful, it's just demonstrating that it will work):

```
def isGameOver(currentBoard):
    return checkGameOver(currentBoard, HUMAN) or checkGameOver(currentBoard, COMPUTER) or getEmptySpots(currentBoard) == []
```

For `minimax`, it would probably be a good idea to make sure there's an initial bestMove, too.

```
def minimax(currentBoard, player):
    if isGameOver(currentBoard):
        score = evaluate(currentBoard)
        return score
    allMoves = getEmptySpots(currentBoard)
    bestMove = allMoves[0]
    for cell in allMoves:
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a logic error inside your loops over the empty cells!
You have to initialize `bestScore` before the loop, and `return bestScore` after the loop. Otherwise `minimax`, `minPlay`, `maxPlay` will always choose the first empty cell.

Here's a fix for `minPlay` (`minimax` and `maxPlay` can be fixed similarly):

```
def minPlay(currentBoard, player):
    if isGameOver(currentBoard):
        score = evaluate(currentBoard)
        return score
    # initialize the "best score" before the loop
    bestScore = 1000000
    for cell in getEmptySpots(currentBoard):
        x = cell[0]
        y = cell[1]
        currentBoard[x][y] = player
        score = maxPlay(currentBoard, -player)
        currentBoard[x][y] = 0
        # update the "best score"
        if score < bestScore:
            bestScore = score
    # return the "best score" after inspecting *all* empty cells
    return bestScore
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense and I implemented the change. However, the algorithm still doesn't seem to recognize the best moves. For example in the picture I just attached (at the very bottom), the computer does not choose to block me from winning.

Comment: Here's my full code. Does this work as expected? https://gist.github.com/flopp/4d38b5eaf138a202f6f8bd89056a9942

Comment: In combination with the answer below it does.